# Python indent region is wrong

Tags: python, indentation

Given the code:

```
def main(args=None):
    if args is None:
        args = sys.argv[1:]
    load_data()
```

Calling `indent-region` on the code (under python mode), the output would be:

```
def main(args=None):
    if args is None:
        args = sys.argv[1:]
        load_data()
```

`load_data` is unexpectedly indented.

Comment: What is `indent-region` supposed to do in a language where indentation is meaningful?

Comment: At least it shall not do something unexpected.  indent-region invokes python-indent-region.  It is more about python-indent-region not working, not about indent-region.